# Nested JSON Array to C# Class

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to pass along a JSON string for an API I'm writing. Here's what the JSON post looks like:

```
{"AssociatedApplication":"Postman", "Key":"a274e012c52d4121bda7d1e7a7218cf5", "Subject":"Testing API", "Body":"Testing email API. Muffins.",
"EmailAddresses":[
    {"From":"apihelp@test.com"},
    {"To":"tus@test.com"},
    {"To":"sam.am@test.com"},
    {"Cc":"sam.am2@test.com"},
    {"Bcc":"sam.am3@test.com"}
]
}
```

Using JSON2Csharp, I have my classes set up as

```
[NotMapped]
class EmailTransmission
{
    public string AssociatedApplication;
    public string Key;
    public string Subject;
    public string Body;
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses;
}

[NotMapped]
public class EmailAddress
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Cc { get; set; }
    public string Bcc { get; set; }
}
```

When I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmailAddress>>(email["EmailAddresses"])` it doesn't work and I've tried `List<List<string>>` List and so forth. What is the type I should use without getting a runtime type binder exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's actually your code, you should be using properties in `EmailTransmission`, not fields.

Second, your class `EmailTransmission` needs to be public.

Finally, you should just deserialize the entire object, then pull out what you need afterwards.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailTransmission>(email);
```

Once you've deserialized the entire json string, you can pull off the email addresses.

Comment: @Dreamcasting happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Please change your EmailTransmission class as belows

```
[NotMapped]
class EmailTransmission
{
    public string AssociatedApplication { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```